# Equipment for analyzing large DC distribution system

Tags: power, dc, power-engineering, test-equipment, constant-power

I'd like obtain the transfer function of a large DC power distribution system. My question is whether there's equipment (like vector network analyzers) designed to
assist with modeling these type of applications. Most equipment seems to be for analyzing power converter PCBs.

Here are some details about the system:

- The system is a large telecom DC distribution system consisting of lead-acid batteries, rectifiers, buswork, and load equipment (essentially constant-power loads).
- The load is approximately 250kW.
- System voltage is 52V under normal conditions. The voltage falls to 48V during battery discharge.
- The load is not in the same room as the rectifiers/batteries. The separation is about 200ft.
- I'm most interested in the network impedance at relative low frequencies (<100Hz).

Comment: You are asking a question that can be answered either yes or no. And, unfortunately if you then changed the question for recommendations, it would become off-topic because shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: measurement only makes sense if you already has modelled your power grid  to compare assumption with reality. No, a NVA is a high frequency tool and the ones I now start at some kHz... they do not measure anything below. Also a Measurement of dynamic characteristics in my understanding would require each Port/Endpoint to be either short circut, open load or terminated with the characteristic impedance (which you do not know).

Comment: So In my perspective you need to set up a valid simulation first and then you can with an osciloscope and or a spectrum analyser test singular points if the simulation is correct.

Comment: Also Tools like a NWA send out ther own testsignals. So you cant use such tools - which are not build for that purpose - when your grid is powered (and it might behave different if not like switchmode power supply, etc...). Also as the net will be of very low impedance you would need strong signals to stimulate a reaction. I doubt such equipment exists.